# Why self-reference a column from the same table in a SQL subquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, self-join, self-reference

I'm working on subqueries in the Google Data Analytics Course. There are many places you can rent bikes from. These places are bike stations. The query is to calculate the difference between average trip length for a particular station and the total trip duration average of all the stations.

There are no JOINs or any data being pulled from a 2nd table.

What does `WHERE column = alias.column` achieve?

Why self-reference a column from the same table in a SQL subquery?

```
SELECT
    starttime,
    start_station_id,
    tripduration,
    (SELECT
        ROUND(AVG(tripduration),2)
    FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
    WHERE start_station_id = outer_trips.start_station_id
    ) AS avg_duration_for_station,
    ROUND(tripduration -
        (SELECT
            ROUND(AVG(tripduration),2)
        FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
        WHERE start_station_id = outer_trips.start_station_id
        ),2) AS difference_from_avg
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips AS outer_trips
LIMIT 25;
```

I expected to get the same result without having to self reference.

Comment: The outer query looks at trips. For every one of those trips it does the subquery as a separate lookup on every single row. Logically it's saying take this station id I've got right here and now go find the average duration for all the other trips *from that station*. That's why it has to be correlated. You can loosely think of it as a function argument.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a self join for? (in english)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352271/what-is-a-self-join-for-in-english)

Comment: "Why specify WHERE column = alias.column. What does that achieve?" You ask us to go through the definition of the subexpressions of an SQL expression & tell you the specification for the rows of each subtable returned or how a part otherwise contributes to other parts. This rewrites the language definition & a tutorial on basics of SQL querying with no details on what you misunderstand or do or don't understand. Do that yourself & say where/how you are 1st stuck. [mre] [rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Comment: "I expected to get the same result without having to self reference." What is stopping you? What does that have to do with your question? Converting between JOINing & subqueries in WHERE or SELECT are faqs. The parts of your overall query/goal are faqs. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts. PS Please format code reasonably per syntax & semantics. Please use a tiny mnemonic alias for every table & dot every column. PS Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question.

Comment: [Replace comparison to scalar subquery by inner join or left/right join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28202970/3404097) [Converting inline query using join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28202970/3404097) etc etc

Comment: "the difference between average trip length for a particular station to the total trip duration average of all the stations" Presumably you mean "between ... and". But it's not clear what you mean by "the total trip duration average of all the stations". Presumably "total" doesn't belong. Regardless it's not clear what "the trip duration average of all the stations" means.--Average of station averages? Average of all trips? Regardless, your query doesn't calculate the difference because your subtraction arguments aren't "average for a particular station" & "average of all the stations".

Answer (score 0):

In [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ta7Snn8b), the query returns this:

| starttime | start_station_id | tripduration | avg_duration_for_station | difference_from_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-15 08:23:47.883618+00 | 1 | 03:44:47.110507 | 03:01:27.152532 | 00:43:19.957975 |
| 2024-01-20 02:24:20.187858+00 | 0 | 00:51:19.64743 | 00:51:19.64743 | 00:00:00 |
| 2024-01-17 02:44:39.358079+00 | 1 | 02:18:07.194556 | 03:01:27.152532 | -00:43:19.957976 |
| 2024-01-15 06:32:48.073332+00 | 2 | 03:52:40.097185 | 03:52:40.097185 | 00:00:00 |

Note that `avg_duration_for_station` depends on station identifier. Removing the "self-reference" removes [*correlation*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/subqueries#correlated_subquery_concepts) of the [scalar subquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/subqueries#scalar_subquery_concepts)  to a given row through `start_station_id`, leaving you with the same, global `avg` everywhere:

| starttime | start_station_id | tripduration | ***avg_duration_for_station*** | difference_from_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-15 08:23:47.883618+00 | 1 | 03:44:47.110507 | ***02:41:43.51242*** | 01:03:03.598087 |
| 2024-01-20 02:24:20.187858+00 | 0 | 00:51:19.64743 | ***02:41:43.51242*** | -01:50:23.86499 |
| 2024-01-17 02:44:39.358079+00 | 1 | 02:18:07.194556 | ***02:41:43.51242*** | -00:23:36.317864 |
| 2024-01-15 06:32:48.073332+00 | 2 | 03:52:40.097185 | ***02:41:43.51242*** | 01:10:56.584765 |

[A window function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls) can have the same effect as those correlated subqueries:

```sql
SELECT
    starttime,
    start_station_id,
    tripduration,
    avg(tripduration) over (w1) AS avg_duration_for_station,
    tripduration - avg(tripduration) over (w1) AS difference_from_avg
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips AS outer_trips
WINDOW w1 AS (partition by start_station_id)
LIMIT 25;
```

You can also [`join`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#left_join) an uncorrelated subquery to your `from` list:

```sql
SELECT starttime,
       start_station_id,
       tripduration,
       avg_duration_for_station,
       tripduration - avg_duration_for_station AS difference_from_avg
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips AS outer_trips
LEFT JOIN (SELECT start_station_id,
                  AVG(tripduration) AS avg_duration_for_station
           FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
           GROUP BY start_station_id
           ) AS station USING (start_station_id)
LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: "the difference between average trip length for a particular station and the total trip duration average of all the stations"

Comment: @philipxy `WHERE start_station_id = outer_trips.start_station_id` in both `avg_duration_for_station` and `difference_from_avg` suggests it's actually station average trip length and trip's deviation from station average. Logic and results match between the two queries above and the original. The *"difference between average trip length for a particular station and the total trip duration average of all the stations"* in the question seems to be OP's not entirely accurate paraphrase of the logic expressed by the query they pasted.

Comment: Yes it's not clear whether their description or their code is what they want. Moreover their description is not clear. See my comment on the question.