# foreign key in databases and creating a join table

Tags: database, relational-database, database-schema

I have question regarding the Associative or the join table we create for the relationship between two entities.
I know the that the foreign key can be NULL in the join table.But should the join table only contain the relationships.As in if in a bank there is a customer(key-id) and a loan(key-id) entity.Let borrow be the relationship between it.Now suppose there are customers who *"haven't taken a loan"*.
So should i take those customers id in the borrow table and the corresponding foreign key for loan-id to  be NULL.Or i shouldn't take those customers in the borrow table.
And what can be a good primary key for the join table.And is the primary key for the join table required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right having a join table between customer and loan.

But you do not need to do anything in this table until there is an actual borrow.

Your primary key for the borrow table should be a **composite primary key**. Made of `customer_id` and `load_id`

Customer

```
customer_id | name  | ...
1           | Jon   | ...
2           | Harry | ...
```

Loan

```
load_id | amount | ...
1       | 1000   | ...
2       | 2000   | ...
```

Borrow

```
customer_id | load_id
1           | 1
1           | 2
```

In this example you can see that Jon has to loans and respectivley there are two records in the borrow table. Harry is a customer, but he has no loan and so there is no record in the borrow table for him.

Comment: What can be a good primary key for borrow.Will it be the composite of the two??

Comment: As described in the answer. You do not need an extra id. The combination of customer_id and load_id is unique and can be used as a composite primary key.

Comment: Is it always a good idea that the primary key be the join of the foreign keys??

Comment: In your join table, yes.

Comment: @AdityaSharma You find the *candidate keys* then you pick one as primary key. Search on finding candidate/primary keys.

Comment: But suppose i have department and employee as an entity and heads as join table with foreign keys as department-id and employee-id.Then it might happen that the department is not headed by anyone thus it will be NULL.and primary keys cannot be null.

Comment: If there's no head, then there is no record in your heads table.

Comment: If this is the answer to your question, please marks as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Every table (base or query result) has a parameterized statement (aka predicate):

- customer [customer_id] has taken out loan [loan_id]
  `Borrows(customer_id,loan_id)`

When you plug in a row like `VALUES (customer_id,loan_id) (8,3)` you get a statement (aka proposition):

- customer 8 has taken loan 3

The rows that make true statements go in the table. The rows that make false statements stay out of the table. So every row that fits in a table makes a statement whether it is in it or not!

The table predicate corresponds to an application relationship wher parameters correspond to columns. A row says something about those values and about identified application entities via them.

*You* pick the application relationships ie table predicates. Then you look at an application situation and put every true row into the tables. Or you look at the tables and see what things are true (per present rows) and false (per absent rows).

Queries also have predicates per their conditions and their logical and relational operators. And their results hold the rows that make them true.

So when someone hasn't taken a loan their `customer_id` doesn't appear in any row in `Borrows`. And when a loan has not been taken by anyone then its `loan_id` doesn't appear in any row of `Borrows`.

If a column can be null then its table's predicate often looks like:

- [name] IS NULL AND [customer_id] identifies a customer
  OR [name] IS NOT NULL
    AND [customer_id] identifies a customer
    AND customer [customer_id] is named [name]
  `Customer(customer_id NOT NULL,name NULL)`

(Using `NULL` in other ways gets even more complicated. And we try to remove `NULL`s in queries as near to when they're introduced as possible.)

We determine candidate keys like usual and pick one as a primary key as ususal. Eg the key for `Borrows` is `(customer_id,name)` because that set's values are unique and there is no smaller unique subset. But determining keys involves columns that are `UNIQUE NOT NULL` (which `PRIMARY KEY` is just a synonym for as a constraint). But we don't ever *need* to use `NULL` in a column because instead of a predicate/table like the above we can have two:

- [customer_id] identifies a customer
  `Customer(customer_id NOT NULL)`
- customer [customer_id] is named [name]
  `Customer(customer_id NOT NULL,name NOT NULL)`

Just like always a row goes in a table if and only if it makes a true statement.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27682724/3404097).