# Confused with mysql statement, three tables

Tags: php, mysql

So i have this problem of printing out table data from 3 different tables as a matrix. And after searching internet, i fanally found a solution to my problem. But i have no idea, how does that mysql statement work. [This is a example that i want to do](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13dtDwjfujkwj4eJmKXSwqFOUajeHiWnyV6mtkJkXyzo/edit#gid=0)

and i think i found a solution so if some one could help explaining me of how it works?

```
SELECT names.codename,
s1.score AS "Score1", s1.comment AS "Comments1",
s2.score AS "Score2", s2.comment AS "Comments2",
SUM(st.score) AS "Total"
FROM students names 
LEFT JOIN scores s1 ON s1.act_id=1 AND names.id=s1.student_id 
LEFT JOIN scores s2 ON s2.act_id=2 AND names.id=s2.student_id 
LEFT JOIN scores st ON names.id=st.student_id
WHERE names.codename <> ''
GROUP BY names.codename
ORDER BY names.codename;

students table:
+----+---------------+
| id | codename      |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Budy          |
+----+---------------+

assignments table:
+--------+------------+
| act_id | name       |
+--------+------------+
|      1 | Activity 1 |
|      2 | Activity 2 |
+--------+------------+

scores table:
+------------+--------+-------+
| student_id | act_id | score |
+------------+--------+-------+
|          1 |      1 |    10 |
|          1 |      2 |    10 |
+------------+--------+-------+
```

Now the problem was, I wanted to have the assignments listed across the top, and the scores next to the names. Something like this:

```
+---------------+------------+------------+-------+
| codename      | Activity 1 | Activity 2 | Total |
+---------------+------------+------------+-------+
|          budy |         10 |         10 |    20 |
+---------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: You can loop through the data and build an array accordingly.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: If you want an arbitrary number of activities, read about [pivoting](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pivot/info) to transpose activity name values to column names. See also [this re predicates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097) then [this re SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27682724/3404097) re composing queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT s.codename, SUM(IF(act.act_id=1, act.score, 0)) AS 'Activity 1', SUM(IF(act.act_id=2, act.score, 0)) AS 'Activity 2', total.score AS 'total' 
FROM
    students s
    INNER JOIN (SELECT student_id, act_id, SUM(score) AS score FROM scores GROUP BY 1, 2) act ON s.id=act.student_id
    INNER JOIN (SELECT student_id, SUM(score) AS score FROM scores GROUP BY 1) total ON s.id=total.student_id
GROUP BY 1
```

This will return results for only the `students` having records in the `scores` table. If you want to list all students, you'll have to change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

### UPDATE

I've updated the query and removed the first sub-query

```
SELECT student_id, act_id, SUM(score) AS score FROM scores GROUP BY 1, 2
```

this is not needed if `student_id` and `act_id` are a composite key so we can use the `scores` table directly. This way the query becomes

```
SELECT s.codename, SUM(IF(act.act_id=1, act.score, 0)) AS 'Activity 1', SUM(IF(act.act_id=2, act.score, 0)) AS 'Activity 2', total.score AS 'total' 
FROM
    students s
    INNER JOIN scores as 'act' ON s.id=act.student_id
    INNER JOIN (SELECT student_id, SUM(score) AS score FROM scores GROUP BY 1) total ON s.id=total.student_id
GROUP BY 1
```

### Explanation

The `JOIN` between `student` and `scores` fetches all scores for all students (I added another student with id `2` and name `Pal`), e.g.

```
+----+----------+------------+--------+-------+
| id | codename | student_id | act_id | score |
+----+----------+------------+--------+-------+
|  1 | Buddy    |          1 |      1 |    10 |
|  1 | Buddy    |          1 |      2 |    10 |
|  2 | Pal      |          2 |      1 |    15 |
|  2 | Pal      |          2 |      2 |    10 |
+----+----------+------------+--------+-------+
```

The sub-query

```
SELECT student_id, SUM(score) AS score FROM scores GROUP BY 1
```

fetches sum of scores for each student like this

```
+------------+-------+
| student_id | score |
+------------+-------+
|          1 |    20 |
|          2 |    25 |
+------------+-------+
```

And we put the results together in the main `SELECT` part using

```
SELECT s.codename, SUM(IF(act.act_id=1, act.score, 0)) AS 'Activity 1', SUM(IF(act.act_id=2, act.score, 0)) AS 'Activity 2', total.score AS 'total'...
```

we add scores if `act_id=1` in column 'Activity 1', similarly we add scores in column 'Activity 2' if `act_id=2` and lastly we use the sum from sub-query as 'total'

I hope this clarifies your questions

Comment: This would be really helpfull if it would be written for these tables [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13dtDwjfujkwj4eJmKXSwqFOUajeHiWnyV6mtkJkXyzo/edit#gid=0). Or you could just explain that statement that you wrote with comments, that i could modify it to fit my tables

Comment: @AudriusJurevičius, please see updated answer with explanation

Comment: when i try to rewrite your code to work on my database like this one [link for my visualized tables that i want to use this code with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13dtDwjfujkwj4eJmKXSwqFOUajeHiWnyV6mtkJkXyzo/edit#gid=0) its does'nt work... And if would have stages of series_DB.stageQ - size, how should i try to update the statement...? :/

Comment: Its difficult to answer without knowing which table/field maps to which table/field in your question

Comment: does this link works for you? [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13dtDwjfujkwj4eJmKXSwqFOUajeHiWnyV6mtkJkXyzo/edit#gid=0](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13dtDwjfujkwj4eJmKXSwqFOUajeHiWnyV6mtkJkXyzo/edit#gid=0), there i made tables that i have, and in the right bottom is a table that i need to generate

Comment: What is info_db? Will this be a table in your db with same values? Or is it only to give an idea of relations? Is it possible that you can create a new question with your actual tables and values? Its very hard to comprehend from the sheet only. You dont have to accept my answer there

Comment: info_db stores position of each player that participaten in n-th stage of a m-th serries. i can try to create another question with more details :/

Comment: grey color columns are primary keys

Comment: @AudriusJurevičius, can you please allow write access to the sheet? Nearly there

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13dtDwjfujkwj4eJmKXSwqFOUajeHiWnyV6mtkJkXyzo/edit?usp=sharing here :)

Comment: @AudriusJurevičius, please check the cell A30 in sheet

Comment: everything works, but when I add more rows to player_DB table, they are added to the printed out table without puting new rows to info_DB table, how could I fix this? So that the finished table would only contain information for serries_ID=1

Comment: Plz share sample data and expecred output

Comment: @nymawaz i have updated https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13dtDwjfujkwj4eJmKXSwqFOUajeHiWnyV6mtkJkXyzo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @AudriusJurevičius. If you want the result to use data of `series_ID=1` only, then adding ` AND s.series_ID=1` to WHERE part of sub-queries of i1, i2 & i3 will do it. I've added this in the sheet

Comment: don't know why but it does'nt help @nymawaz